# Overwriting a file using Spring mina SFTP

Tags: spring, client, sftp, apache-mina

I have created a client based on the example on the Spring web page

https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/sftp/inbound.html#configuring-with-java-configuration

I did change the setMaxFetchSize to -1 to transfer all of the files from the remote site and the SftpSimplePatternFileListFilter to '*.html' as I want to transfer web pages.

The problem is that the first run of the code tranfsers the files but subsequent runs display the following message

> The remote file 'xxxxx.html' has not been transferred to the existing
> local file 'sftp-inbound\xxxxxx.html'. Consider removing the local
> file.

The web pages are generated and transferred to the SFTP server every 5 minutes. I'd like to overwrite the local files if a new version of the file exists on the server. I have looked though the Spring documentation but can't see a method defined to do this. How can the local files be overwritten?

Answer (score 0):

I am a beginner with **Spring** and I did find the documentation useful but there are a lot of things not mentioned in it that I needed to find from elsewhere.

I ended up with a mashup the **Configuring with Java Configuration** and **Configuring with Java DSL** (link below) as I wanted to preserve the timestamp of the files from the server. The **@Poller** annotation does not appear to have an option to preserve a timestamp:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/sftp/inbound.html#configuring-with-the-java-dsl

The **Configuring with Java DSL** seems to be missing the following declaration in the class:

```
private DefaultSftpSessionFactory sftpSessionFactory;
```

In the **Sftp.inboundAdapter** I added the following filter - the default **AcceptOnceFileListFilter** seems to only transfer the files the first time. If the files are updated on the remote system, they are not downloaded again.

```
                                .filter(new AcceptAllFileListFilter<>())
```

As I wanted to transfer all the updated files I set the **maxFetchSize** to -1 (negative numbers indicate all files)

```
                                .maxFetchSize(-1)
```

This still didn't transfer all of the updated files so I also had to add the following to the poller

```
                                        .maxMessagesPerPoll(-1)))
```

The final IntegrationFlow is below - note that **remote_dir** is a **String** set earlier in the class.

```
        return IntegrationFlow
                .from(Sftp.inboundAdapter(this.sftpSessionFactory)
                                .preserveTimestamp(true)
                                .maxFetchSize(-1)
                                .deleteRemoteFiles(false)
                                .filter(new AcceptAllFileListFilter<>())
                                .remoteDirectory(remote_dir)
                                .patternFilter("*.html")
                                .localDirectory(new File("html")),
                        e -> e.id("sftpInboundAdapter")
                                .autoStartup(true)
                                .poller(Pollers
                                        .fixedDelay(300000)
                                        .maxMessagesPerPoll(-1)))
                .handle(m -> System.out.println("Transferring updated file " + m.getPayload()))
                .get();
```